# Need to get difference of alternative consecutive rows in a table using Sql query

Tags: sql

Could any one help me solving the following query.

My table:

```
pkId | DateTime
------------------
 1     2011-07-01 09:33:00
 5     2011-07-01 14:01:00
 7     2011-07-01 14:06:00
 9     2011-07-01 19:18:00
```

I need to get the difference of times between first and second row, third and fourth row.

Result:

```
(14:01:00 - 09:33:00)
(19:18:00 - 14:06:00)
```

Regards,
Bharath

Comment: Why not differences between 2nd and 3rd row too?

Comment: requirement is to neglect that time. I want to calculate the total work time excluding that time.

Comment: What SQL engine and version please?

Comment: Is there really nothing else special that denotes start and end rows for each period? Is it possible for there to be an odd number of rows in the table, and if so, how do the pairings work out there, and what is done with the left over row?

Comment: hi,Actually there will be even number of rows.

Comment: And what was wrong with storing the timestamps as `StartDateTime` & `EndDateTime`?

Comment: If this is oracle or sql server there is a simple solution using a windowed function other RDBMS it gets a little more complicated can you post your RDBMS platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lag function in oracle as follow -

```
select * from 
 (
     select t_1.*,datetime - LAG(datetime , 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY pkId), rownum c_1 from 
      ( 
              select pkId , DateTime FROM my_table order by pkId 
      ) t_1
 )
where c_1%2 = 0
```

i think you can understand this one.. explanation is not required .. right??